# How to make Alert.alert message copy and paste-able?

Tags: react-native, alert

Here is a `Alert.alert()` in RN 0.63.2:

```
import {  Alert } from "react-native";

Alert.alert(
'Alert Title',
'My Alert Msg',  //<<==how to enable copy & paste on this message?
{ cancelable: false }
)
```

There is sensitive information in `My Alert Msg` which user wants to copy and paste. How can I make the message copy & paste-able for user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are setting the message text from a state or veriable why not just call a function on button click in the alert and have it copy the veriable or state contents to clip board ?

```
Alert.alert('Alert Title', this.state.message, [ {text: 'Copy message', onPress: () => this.CopyAlertMessage(), style: 'cancel'}, {text: 'close alert', onPress: () => this.closeAlert()}, ], { cancelable: true});
```

and then have your function like so

```
CopyAlertMessage = async () => {
    Clipboard.setString(this.state.message)
}
```

just remember to import Clipboard from react-native